# write-file-functions: Clarification as to permanent local behavior with add-hook

Tags: local-variables

According to the `write-file-functions` doc-string, "*[t]his variable's value is permanent if it is given a local binding.*"

- Step 1:  Start from `emacs -q` using Emacs 25.2.1.
- Step 2:  Switch to the `*scratch*` buffer.
- Step 3:  Type the following in the `*scratch*` buffer, so that it gets modified and so that we can later evaluate what we typed.

  `(add-hook 'write-file-functions (lambda () (message "hello-world")) 'append 'local)`
- Step 4:  Evaluate the statement that we typed in Step 3 above -- e.g., `C-x C-e`
- Step 5:  `M-x save-buffer` and save it anywhere that is appropriate.  I chose to call the file `foo` and I saved it as `~/Desktop/foo`
- Step 6:  `M-x describe-variable RET write-file-functions RET`; or, `C-h v` and then the name of the variable we are looking up.

  `write-file-functions is a variable defined in ‘files.el’.`

  `Its value is nil`

I expected the `write-file-functions` hook to maintain the original value because it is `permanent` when given a local binding.  Why is my assumption incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `write-file-functions`

> write-file-functions is a variable defined in ‘files.el’.
>
> This variable’s value is permanent if it is given a local binding.
>     This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
>
> Documentation:
>   List of functions to be called before saving a buffer to a file.
>   Only used by ‘save-buffer’.
>
> If one of them returns non-nil, the file is considered already written
>   and the rest are not called.
>
> **These hooks are considered to pertain to the visited file.
>   So any buffer-local binding of this variable is discarded if you change
>   the visited file name with M-x set-visited-file-name, but not when you
>   change the major mode.**
>
> This hook is not run if any of the functions in
>   ‘write-contents-functions’ returns non-nil.  Both hooks pertain
>   to how to save a buffer to file, for instance, choosing a suitable
>   coding system and setting mode bits.  (See Info
>   node ‘(elisp)Saving Buffers’.)  To perform various checks or
>   updates before the buffer is saved, use ‘before-save-hook’.

Answer (score 1):

No explanation, but here are some observations:

1. I can reproduce this with `emacs -Q`.
2. In the help to this var is stated: `This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.`
   This line is added dynamically, it is not stated in the source `files.el`
3. You are saving a buffer without a file (`*scratch*`) to a file. The buffer `*scratch*` does not exist afterwards, but you have a new buffer called `foo`.

   If you redo your `(add-hook ...)` inside the new buffer `foo` and then save the `foo` buffer with the already given name, this `write-file-functions` variable keeps it value.
4. Doing the same with a local variable `(set (make-local-variable 'foo) "value")` keeps the variable value always.

And then, I do not know emacs nor elisp good enough. :(